# Using count sql query giving "Invalid column name" error in Java Program

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc

How can i use this sql query in Java Program.

```
String SelectSQL = "SELECT (CASE WHEN cnt >= 1
                             THEN 'True'
                             ELSE 'False'
                             END) result_str
                 FROM ( SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM event WHERE externaleventid ='1256294' )";
```

I am using Preparatory statement to pass the externaleventid. Other query works fine when I am using column name but when I don't use column name I am getting the error "Invalid column name" When I run this query in SQL developer it executes successfully.

Added java code:

```
String query = " SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) >= 1 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END) AS result_str FROM event WHERE externaleventid = ?";
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
pstmt.setString(1,"1256294");
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) { 
    String externaleventid = rs.getString("DISPLAYNAME");
    System.out.println("externaleventid : " + externaleventid);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the actual Java that you're running, that makes this fail?

Comment: Also, that SQL is way more complicated than it needs to be.  You could just write `SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) >= 1 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END) AS result_str FROM event WHERE externaleventid = '1256294'`

Comment: After creating jdbc connection i am using the following code: Other queries work fine except for the Counting if a unique value is present or not String query = " SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) >= 1 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END) AS result_str FROM event WHERE externaleventid = ?"; PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query); pstmt.setString(1,"1256294"); ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery(); while (rs.next()) { String externaleventid = rs.getString("DISPLAYNAME"); System.out.println("externaleventid : " + externaleventid);

Comment: You are trying to get the result from a column named `DISPLAYNAME` which does not exist. Use `rs.getString(1)` to get the result by index number rather than by name.  If you want to use a name, reference the alias you use: `rs.getString("result_str")`.

Comment: @Glenn That is the correct answer.  If you post it as an answer, I will upvote it, and hopefully the OP will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You should write

```
         "SELECT (CASE WHEN cnt >= 1
                         THEN 'True'
                         ELSE 'False'
                         END) AS result_str
             FROM ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM event WHERE externaleventid ='1256294' )";
```

instead of

```
        "SELECT (CASE WHEN cnt >= 1
                         THEN 'True'
                         ELSE 'False'
                         END) result_str
             FROM ( SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM event WHERE externaleventid ='1256294' )";
```

Comment: Still i am getting same error. I am looking for unique result if it is available or not in specific externaleventid column in my java program

Comment: After creating jdbc connection i am using the following code: Other queries work fine except for the Counting if a unique value is present or not String query = " SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) >= 1 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END) AS result_str FROM event WHERE externaleventid = ?";
        PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query); 
      
pstmt.setString(1,"1256294"); 
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();       
 while (rs.next()) {  
String externaleventid = rs.getString("DISPLAYNAME");     System.out.println("externaleventid : " + externaleventid);

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the result from a column named `DISPLAYNAME` which does not exist in your query. One option is to ignore the name and retrieve by index:

```
rs.getString(1);
```

Another is to retrieve by name, but use the name of the alias that was on the query:

```
rs.getString("result_str");
```